# Speeding up select where column condition exists in another table without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have the following two tables:

1. Table "a" with 2 columns: id (int) [Primary Index], column1 [Indexed]
2. Table "b" with 3 columns: id_table_a (int),condition1 (int),condition2 (int) [all columns as Primary Index]

I can run the following query to select rows from Table a where Table b condition1 is 1

```
SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.id_table_a=a.id && condition1=1 LIMIT 1) ORDER BY a.column1 LIMIT 50
```

With a couple hundred million rows in both tables this query is very slow. If I do:

```
SELECT a.id FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a && b.condition1=1  ORDER BY a.column1 LIMIT 50
```

It is pretty much instant but if there are multiple matching rows in table b that match id_table_a then duplicates are returned. If I do a SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY a.id to remove duplicates the query becomes extremely slow.

Here is an SQLFiddle showing the example queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35eb9e/10

Is there a way to make a join without duplicates fast in this case?

*Edited to show that INNER instead of LEFT join didn't make much of a difference

*Edited to show moving condition to join did not make much of a difference

*Edited to add LIMIT

*Edited to add ORDER BY

Comment: Approx how many rows are returned from the raw (fast) join version?

Comment: Sorry I added the LIMIT 50 to the question now. It should return 50 or whatever small limit out of the hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: Is the `order by` really required? Will any 50 do?

Comment: The ORDER BY is required yes. I added that as well now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with inner join and distinct

```
SELECT distinct a.id 
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a AND b.condition1=1
```

but using distinct on select * be sure you don't distinct id that return wrong result in this case use

```
SELECT distinct col1, col2, col3 .... 
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a AND b.condition1=1
```

You could also add a composite index with use also condtition1  eg: key(id, condition1)

if you can you could also perform a

```
 ANALYZE TABLE table_name;
```

on both the table  ..

and another technique is try to reverting  the lead table

```
SELECT distinct a.id 
FROM b INNER JOIN a ON a.id=b.id_table_a AND b.condition1=1
```

Using the most selective table for lead the query

Using this seem different the use of index  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35eb9e/15 (the last add a using where)

```
# USING DISTINCT TO REMOVE DUPLICATES without col  and order 
 EXPLAIN 
 SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
 FROM a 
 INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a AND b.condition1=1
;
```

Comment: I tried using DISTINCT but it slows down the query by an extreme amount. For some reason having a join with a couple duplicates is tons faster then a join with DISTINCT. When using DISTINCT a.id

Comment: $condition1 is a column ? if yes try adding this column (or the releated column) to an index eg: key(id, condition1)

Comment: yes condition1 is a column and part of the primary index with id_table_a which is why the join query with duplicates is very fast

Comment: But if all the info  are in index .. should be reasonably fast also the filter for distinct .. how many rows you have in your table?

Comment: Unfortunately if I use distinct it takes a couple minutes to load. ~100 million in table a, ~500 million in table b. But if I remove the distinct it loads almost instantly.

Comment: I did an analyze on both and they are both OK. The reverting lead table query is about as slow as well unfortunately.

Comment: update you answer and show you index . both the table  .. and check  if in explain plan the queries use the most useful index ..

Comment: The explains are in this SQLFiddle now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35eb9e/4 now, they seem to be using the most useful index

Comment: I have slightly  modified one of your query .. avoiding distinct(a.id) but using  distinct  a.id   .. otherwise  if you need distinct seem you have now faster solution

Comment: distinct a.id doesn't seem to make a difference in my case. Damn I don't know why MYSQL has to make it so hard to make a simple join without duplicates fast

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found the answer.

```
SELECT a.id FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON 
    b.id_table_a=a.id && 
    b.condition1=1 && 
    b.condition2=(select b.condition2 from b WHERE b.id_table_a=a.id && b.condition1=1 LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY a.column1
LIMIT 5;
```

I don't know if there is a flaw in this or not, please let me know if so. If anyone has a way to compress this somehow I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: I couldn't believe this one would be faster than the original EXISTS-solution until i tested it. The performance difference is huge. Here are some variations of that solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09ac84/15 - The first two conditions don't need to use a subquery. The last condition ist the one that removes the duplicates.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't believe it either until I tested it and it's the fastest solution out of all of them right now (pretty much instant) and the simplest (when compressed). Thanks for your compressed version. I was too tired to notice the 2 subqueries were unnecessary but for some reason probably due to the optimizer cache it's just as fast as the compressed version you have.  If you edit your answer with the compressed version you have then I will accept that one as it's the most correct and performant of all of them so far

Comment: @jjj AFAICT this is not the same as your original query, because the new query restricts `condition2` to being a single randomly chosen value of all the possible values. To be the same, you would need to change `b.condition2=(select b.condition2 from b WHERE b.id_table_a=a.id && b.condition1=1 LIMIT 1)` to `b.condition2 IN (select b.condition2 from b WHERE b.id_table_a=a.id && b.condition1=1)` - ie remove the `LIMIT`

Comment: It seems to return the exact same results as the EXISTS query. All I wanted was a quick way to SELECT if a joined column (b.condition1 in this case) is a certain value. I'm not selecting b.condition2 and do not care about it's value in this case. All that matters in this case is to select row a if b.id_table_a is a.id and b.condition1 is 1.

Comment: @Bohemian - the `IN` condition wothout `LIMIT 1` can return multiple rows per ID, but the EXISTS-query wouldn't. Because `condition2` is part of the primary key, it's unique for given ID and `condition1`. Having `LIMIT 1` in the condition we tell, that only one row should pass the condition for given ID and condition1. We don't care which one, because we don't select it, so it can be "random" (in fact it's `min(condition2)`).

Comment: @JJJ - I don't wont to copy your answer. It's your solution! And it's good. So just accept your own answer.

Comment: @paul yes, I know. That's the point: This query discards rows that could/should be in the final result. You need the order by on condition1 over the *entire* matching rowset to get the same final 50 rows as the original query. This query gives 50 rows, but almost certainly not the *same* 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a AND b.condition1=1
```

Take the condition into the `ON` clause of the join, that way the index of table b can get used to filter. Also use `INNER JOIN` over `LEFT JOIN`

Then you should have less results which have to be grouped.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately if I move the condition to the inner join  it will still cause duplicates and when I added SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY a.id to remove duplicates it was too slow.

Comment: Can you give us a small sample of how your data looks like and what the result should be? Best via sqlfiddle. I set one up like this, does it look correct? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af1e68/3

Comment: yeah that's perfect but my tables have >100 million rows for each table. Here is the explain when I have a simple join with distinct: http://pasteboard.co/2VrzV0da6.png

Here is the explain without the distinct: http://pasteboard.co/2Vs4X1rmR.png

I have a LIMIT 50 on both queries btw.

Comment: Have you tried removing the limit? Wild guessing, but in some cases it can slow queries down

Comment: I can't remove that otherwise it would try and grab 100 million rows. Here's an SQLFiddle showing the explain differences so you can see how they use temporary tables or filesorts (I added an order by as that is what I would be using as well): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35eb9e/4

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the fast version in a query that handles de-duping and limit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
  SELECT a.id
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.id = b.id_table_a && b.condition1 = 1
) x
ORDER BY column1
LIMIT 50
```

We know the inner query is fast. The de-duping and ordering has to happen somewhere. This way it happens on the smallest rowset possible.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35eb9e/38).

---

Option 2:

Try the following:

Create indexes as follows:

```
create index a_id_column1 on a(id, column1)
create index b_id_table_a_condition1 on b(a_table_a, condition1)
```

These are *covering* indexes - ones that contain all the columns you need for the query, which in turn means that index-only access to data can achieve the result.

Then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.id, MIN(a.column1) column1
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.id = b.id_table_a
    AND b.condition1 = 1
  GROUP BY a.id) x
ORDER BY column1
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I think this is the closest so far. How would I go about adding a limit though. Having a limit on the inner query misses rows and having a limit on the outside makes the entire query extremely slow. Some rows have 100k+ duplicates.

Comment: There's no getting around the ordering, which has an O(n log n) time complexity. I think that's your (unfortunately unavoidable) problem here.

Comment: Try the posted new query. It might work well. 100K is not a "big" number of rows to sort.

Comment: I tried it out and due to there being 100 million rows in one table it has to select all 100 million before sorting by id.

Comment: Thanks for your help you lead me somewhat in the right direction. What do you think of the answer I put? It loads blazingly fast but I'm not sure if there is a major flaw with the 3 separate subqueries.

Comment: @JJJ Try option 2 in my answer

Comment: option 2 seems to be slow as well unfortunately. The answer I have above is pretty much instant so this is basically solved on my end. If you have something that's faster and or simpler then Paul's compressed version let me know though.

Answer (score 0):

Use your fast query in a subselect and remove the duplicates in the outer select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.id
FROM (
    SELECT a.id 
    FROM a 
    INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a && b.condition1=1
    WHERE b.id_table_a > :offset
    ORDER BY a.column1
    LIMIT 50
) sub
```

Because of removing duplicates you might get less than 50 rows. Just repeat the query until you get anough rows. Start with `:offset = 0`. Use the last ID from last result as `:offset` in the following queries.

If you know your statistics, you can also use two limits. The limit in the inner query should be high enough to return 50 distinct rows with a probability which is high enough for you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.id
FROM (
    SELECT a.id 
    FROM a 
    INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_table_a && b.condition1=1
    ORDER BY a.column1
    LIMIT 1000
) sub
LIMIT 50
```

For example: If you have an average of 10 duplicates per ID, `LIMIT 1000` in the inner query will return an average of 100 distinct rows. Its very unlikely that you get less than 50 rows.

If the `condition2` column is a boolean, you know that you can have a maximum of two duplicates. In this case `LIMIT 100` in the inner query would be enough.

Comment: The average varies widely. Many rows have 100k+ duplicates (probably a million for some of them but I haven't checked). So limit 100000 would be very slow as I collect a lot more than just id in the real world.